# How to change IP address using perl

Tags: perl, ip, ip-address, dhcp

I am beginner to Perl and I have to write a script which could change the IP address after every 1 hour.
I want to change it because I receive some data from a dongle from a website and that website has some time limit to receive that data, so currently we need to unplug that dongle and use another to
change IP address. (I mean I have to request DHCP for another IP.)

But currently I am asked to write a script using Perl. Could someone please help me how to do that?

Comment: On windows, you could use command line tool `ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew`. Could very likely get the same address back, though. Nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 3):

It's too broad. Have a look at [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm) module, read the documentation and you're good to go.

Comment: Oklet me try ..will let u know if i get something

Comment: But could you please basic idea of how the things work? I mean how IP address can be changed ? Any logic for how we will request IP from DHCP and will set it ?

Comment: You can use `system` command and do a release/renew operation like `ikegami` suggested.

Comment: you mean writting a perl script which do iconfig  release /renew after every hour ? something like that ? (but ikegami also say that you will get the same address though)

Comment: yes, he's right. can't help it.